# Is there an alternative for the error_page 497 option from nginx for haproxy?

Tags: nginx, ssl, haproxy, 301-redirect

When using nginx I can just use the 497 error code specific to nginx

> 497 HTTP Request Sent to HTTPS Port

and redirect to https with this rule:

```
error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
```

When using haproxy the only solution I know of is to use two ports e.g. port 80 and 443 but I only have one port (8443).

I tried the `errorloc` option but when a client tries to connect to the https port I get an ssl handshare error that can not be catched with the `errorloc` option.

Ideally I would use the following but that does not work:

```
frontend http-in
    bind :8443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/ssl/fullchain.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    maxconn 50

    default_backend backend-server
```

Comment: You can't run HTTP and HTTPS on the same port. Full stop.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thats not what Im trying to do, I want to redirect the user to https in case the user made a http request e.g. on ssl handshake error I want to redirect to https, this is perfectly possible with nginx so why wouldnt this be possible with haproxy ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton turns out this is possible with haproxy just like its possible with nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it turns out that this can indeed be achieved with HAProxy
(one port for https and http and redirecting all http requests to https)

I finally found a solution in the HAProxy forum from [lukastribus](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/one-port-to-catch-http-and-https-requests-and-redirect-to-the-https-version/1703/2?u=elovin).

**The following example is from [lukastribus](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/one-port-to-catch-http-and-https-requests-and-redirect-to-the-https-version/1703/2?u=elovin):**

```
frontend port801_combined
    mode tcp
    bind :801
    tcp-request inspect-delay 2s
    tcp-request content accept if HTTP
    tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }
    use_backend recir_http if HTTP
    default_backend recir_https

backend recir_http
    mode tcp
    server loopback-for-http abns@haproxy-http send-proxy-v2
backend recir_https
    mode tcp
    server loopback-for-https abns@haproxy-https send-proxy-v2

frontend fe-https
    mode http
    bind abns@haproxy-https accept-proxy ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/unified-cert-file.pem
    # whatever you need todo for HTTPS traffic
frontend fe-http
    mode http
    bind abns@haproxy-http accept-proxy
    # whatever you need todo for HTTP traffic
```

By adding

```
redirect scheme https code 301
```

To the frontend fe-http section like this:

```
frontend fe-http
    mode http
    bind abns@haproxy-http accept-proxy
    redirect scheme https code 301
```

All http requests will be redirected to https.